# How is everyone surviving the COVID19 outbreak?

Tags: discussion

Look I'd probably close this question myself if I saw it, but there's nothing much else on the telly and we're all trying to fend off the zombie apocalypse.

What are we all doing to survive the outbreak and the resulting isolation? Most TV/Film productions are shutting down - there's some sound post production work on the horizon, but not a lot.

Funniest answer wins. We can then delete all of this once they find a cure.

Answer (score 3):

My answer is far too sensible. My entire team is scattered across the globe anyway, so we all use video conferencing for every meeting.

So - absolutely business as usual.

My wife is off work at the moment - as a nurse, but also in high risk category, she needs to isolate.
My kids' school is now closing, so they will learn via classes through Microsoft Teams. And kids seem to communicate with each other via TikTok, SnapChat, Instagram etc so I don't think that side of things will impact them at all. And we are next to fields and trees so they can go out and about to burn off any energy.

Bit gutted I have had to cancel some gigs I was going to see, and my band is looking at streaming our one on the 6th of April online from our lead singer's front room - we'll see

Toilet roll - hmmm. As a family of 5 it gets used up faster than you'd think, but shops haven't had any for a week, so that may well be a minor issue at some point. Not the end of the world though.

Answer (score 3):

Seems as a good a place to shill as any --- I'm working on my 3D scanner for small (and big) things using a USB microscope and 3D printer! https://hackaday.io/project/169362-ladybug-beefy-3d-printer-motorized-microscope

I'm in the process of finally converting it to proper GCODE controls and adding support for a better camera.

Mostly I'm just going nuts though.

Answer (score 2):

Me? I'm walking the dog mostly and keeping the gear clean in the unlikely case I get press-ganged into action.

I'm trying to avoid going to costco. We don't need any more toilet roll for a week or so so we'll cross that bridge when we come to it.

I'm currently writing some documentation on keeping film sets safe for sound crew in the present climate.

http://bit.ly/COVID_19_SOUND_PROTOCOL if anyone wants to read it all and help me improve it.

Comment: I looked at your covid for sound techs… I'd add, "Close mic case/cupboard, lock mic case/cupboard, don't let anyone breathe near it until given clear instructions this was all just a dream" ;)

Answer (score 2):

I seem to be spending far too much time just staring at my computer, waiting for an email to come in, telling me it was all just a big joke & all the productions are restarting on Monday. hope you enjoyed your week off.

I even tried my agent to see if there was anything still running I could sneak a day or two on… there isn't. The UK film/TV industry is closed. No-one, but no-one, is shooting anything.

At least the supermarket queues have subsided - for two reasons, one, everybody's fridge, freezer & garage is now full to the brim; & two, the stores are completely empty.
…unless you like steak. For some reason they had half a hundredweight of steak, but little else.

I did figure out you could still scrape a meal for the whole family out of the 'damaged or sell-by-date' stock with the big yellow stickers.
By next week, we'll be hunting in the bins out the back ;)

Re: toilet roll, last week we needed some - probably 4 would have been fine, a 12-pack if we're stocking up - unfortunately the main stocks had already  gone but they'd got a special pallet just in, so we ended up with a pack of 16. Judging by the amount of loo roll, white rice & pasta everyone else seemed to 'need' they've all now got a lifetime's supply.

So to pass the time & avoid watching daytime TV - which would feel like i'd totally given up & was just waiting for the zombies to break the door down - I've taken to 'faffing'.
This is procrastination with a 'purpose', even if the purpose is just to fill time - I wonder if that software I blagged from so-&-so last year under the pretence of actively beta-testing is really any use to me?

oh… & for the first time in my life I rinsed a beer can before opening it.
Paranoia is contagious too ;)

*Late edit*
Right now I'm listening to Boris Johnson's daily report from 10 Downing Street.
All the sound engineers were apparently sent home, his mic is so hot it's glowing… & no-one is backing the level off… we're doomed ;-)

*xmas update*
Situation almost still the same. Productions have opened back up but everything else is shut down tight.
One thing I can say is I've never had so many bottle-brushes stuck up my nose as I get these days. Covid testing is at least twice a week… some productions are even daily - they have everybody spread out outdoors & no-one is allowed into base before they get a clean result.
Roll on the vaccine…

One very noticeable difference is that back in March most people only heard of cases in the news… now everybody knows personally half a dozen families who are going through it or come out the other side.

Comment: That sucks! Up here, though, there are jobs going at all the supermarkets, as their high risk/pregnant/elderly folks self isolate, so my eldest two are probably going to apply to at least get some income, and to be there putting stock on shelves and manning checkouts.

Comment: they'll have plenty to do if that's what they choose. The supermarkets here [North London] are totally wiped, except for [very bizarrely] steak. if you want steak, it's in abundance. Otherwise, they're doing a good line in grey-painted shelves ;)

Answer (score 2):

I’m over in the USA and the third confirmed case in our county (San Bernardino) was a family friend. She is fine just a fever off and on but she’s been home with no medical attention needed.

I have been ordered to stay home with pay so I might just work on recording a personal project that I’ve been putting off but now I have no excuse.

Hope you are all doing well and able to make the best out of this time.

Answer (score 2):

I just caught the invite that said anybody, so "Hi, I'm anybody", anyway I know next to nothing about sound equipment. Personally, I'm a bored, retired professional driver in the States, but I my forte is grammar, page layout and editing, so I will judge your documentation on that.. (hold the groans for real infection please)

Finished my scan.. a spell check... all good. A missed comma.. or two. the absense of bold text in an entire bold sentence was mildly confusing.. but what does a Yank know.. :) Over all a well written document.

**We can accomplish much by isolating ourselves and thinking inside a box.**

Answer (score 2):

### Netflix and chill... in the car!

At least a couple times a month, my wife and I usually leave the kids at home and go out on a date night to keep ourselves sane and the relationship healthy.  Since all the businesses are shuttered, we had to improvise this time.  We hit up a drive through, pulled into a big empty parking lot, and streamed a movie through my phone.

Dinner, a movie, and a little fooling around afterward? It's like the most perfect date we've ever been on!  LOL

Comment: Yeah that's the way to do it!

Comment: I am starting to think that Drive-in cinemas are going to become a thing again...